# GitHub: How to check if i already have the current master branch zip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, python-requests

I try to check if i already have the current version of the master branch of a repository on GitHub. I would expect this to work with the `ETag` so that if i provide the last saved `ETag` to my request and the `ETag` is the same as the remote one, then i don't need to download it again.

I use this code to check this:

```
import requests


etag_old = '"8ec0bb526b1b281a450669d79ca9ed0c7ff6b4f2"'
headers = {"If-None-Match": etag_old}

# Also doesn't work: https://codeload.github.com/Endogen/OpenCryptoBot/zip/master
response = requests.get("https://github.com/Endogen/OpenCryptoBot/archive/master.zip", headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(f"Status-Code: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"New ETag: {response.headers.get('ETag')}")
    print(f"History: {response.history}")
    print(f"URL: {response.url}")
else:
    # If we get status code 304, it's working
    print(f"Status-Code: {response.status_code}")
```

Strangely enough, this doesn't work. Also the URL in `response.url` doesn't work. It has something todo with the URL since this works:

```
import requests


etag_old = '"29b127a376b492572f7e332ba5dd38ea89d4d37c"'
headers = {"If-None-Match": etag_old}

response = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/endogen/Telegram-Kraken-Bot/master/telegram_kraken_bot.py", headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(f"Status-Code: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"New ETag: {response.headers.get('ETag')}")
    print(f"History: {response.history}")
    print(f"URL: {response.url}")
else:
    # If we get status code 304, it's working
    print(f"Status-Code: {response.status_code}")
```

My question is: How can i reliably check if i already have the current master branch version?

I'm using Python 3.7

Comment: Why aren't you using git and cloning the repo?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1Because in the environment i use there is no git. What i have to do is: 1) get content from master 2) extract the zip 3) replace local content with downloaded content. I only want to do that if there is something new in the repo of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides `Etag`, you can also use [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to check branch info.

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/Endogen/OpenCryptoBot/branches/master
```

And you can store and use the commit hash just like `Etag` to decide whether to download or not:

```
{
  "name": "master",
  "commit": {
    "sha": "a20434b7d213ff1321b7eaf896246dbf67b9fdbd",
    ...
```

But I wonder if you are allowed to run python script, maybe it's ok to first install git in your script. And if that's the case, it's the most painless way and there's a nice lib called [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) to interact with git.

Comment: Really nice solution! Didn't thought about the GitHub API. That will work perfectly. Also GitPython is a nice hint but i don't need it for this.